# Create data.frame from ezANOVA output

Tags: r, anova

I've just ran a mixed ANOVA using `ezANOVA` and I need to create a data frame with the output for extraction into an Rmd but I cannot find any information on how to do it.

I've previously used `aov()` and `broom::tidy()`, however `tidy()` cannot format the output I get from the ezANOVA. I've tried `as.data.frame` but it results is a very messy data frame so I'd rather not use it. Does anybody know of a solution which gives an easy to read data frame similar to `tidy()`?

My ANOVA:

```r
library(ez)

aov <- b <- ezANOVA(data=exp1.long,
        dv=consensus,
        wid=participant_id,
        within=trait,
        between=age_group,
        type=3,
        detailed=T 
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! By following this guide [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you provide a solid basis for answering this question. In particular, it's mostly necessary to provide an [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example). Check out [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4573108) for tips regarding R-specific MCVEs. Good look and thank you for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `return_aov = TRUE`?

```
 b <- ezANOVA(data=exp1.long,
      dv=consensus,
      wid=participant_id,
      within=trait,
      between=age_group,
      type=3,
      detailed=T 
    return_aov = TRUE
    )
```

The `return_aov` command, if set on `TRUE`, computes and returns an `aov` object corresponding to the requested `ANOVA` (useful for computing post-hoc contrasts).

See for details:
https://rdrr.io/cran/ez/man/ezANOVA.html

Answer (score 0):

The trick is:

```
df <- as.data.frame(print(aov))
```

We can then check the resulting `df` class to confirm it worked correctly:

```
class(df)
"data.frame"
```

And check the output (note: used my own data):

```
df
  ANOVA.Effect ANOVA.DFn ANOVA.DFd   ANOVA.F    ANOVA.p ANOVA.p..05    ANOVA.ges
2        COND1         1        53 4.1938628 0.01947959           * 0.0070548612
3        COND2         1        53 3.6018758 0.02962809           * 0.0040817987
4  COND1:COND2         1        53 0.8371797 0.24026453             0.0008646178
```

**Explanation:** It is true that the `return_aov = TRUE` argument adds an `aov` object, which can provide similar results when used as `summary(aov$aov)`. However, the result is still not a dataframe, and trying `as.data.frame(summary(aov$aov))` outputs `Error in as.data.frame.default(summary(aov$aov)) : cannot coerce class ‘"summary.aovlist"’ to a data.frame`.

Hopefully, this provides the outcome you were looking for.